# How to correctly combine these two queries?

Tags: sql, sqlite

`Employees` table :

| EmpID (Primary Key) | LastName | FirstName |
| --- | --- | --- |

`Orders` table :

| OrderID (Primary Key) | CustID | EmpID | OrderDate | RequiredDate | ShippedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I need a query which returns `EmpID`, `LastName`, `FirstName`, total number of orders by employee, and total number of orders shipped late. An order is late if its `ShippedDate` is 5 days after `RequiredDate`. I got the late shipments by :

```
julianday(ShippedDate) - julianday(RequiredDate) >= 5
```

I thought to make two separate queries, one that takes a total count of the submissions and one for total count of late orders, then `UNION` them. I'm not getting the result I am looking for:

```
SELECT Employees.EmpId, Employees.LastName, Employees.FirstName, COUNT(*) as TotalCount, NULL
FROM Orders, Employees
WHERE Orders.EmpID = Employees.EmpID
GROUP BY LastName
UNION
SELECT Employees.EmpId, Employees.LastName, Employees.FirstName, NULL, COUNT(*) as LateCount
FROM Orders, Employees
WHERE Orders.EmpID = Employees.EmpID
AND julianday(ShippedDate) - julianday(RequiredDate) >= 5
GROUP BY LastName
```

I end up with offset null values on right side of the table :

| TotalCount | NULL |
| --- | --- |
| 17 | NULL |
| NULL | 25 |

etc.

1. What went wrong with my UNION? Why is the data offset and the column header wrong?
2. Is there a better approach?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055)

Comment: *What went wrong with my UNION?* UNION uses the columns names from the most 1st subquery, and ignores the columns names from another subqueries. So you must use `SELECT Employees.EmpId, Employees.LastName, Employees.FirstName, COUNT(*) as TotalCount, NULL as LateCount` which will assign needed alias to the last column.

Comment: *Is there a better approach?* Conditional aggregation. `SELECT Employees.EmpId, Employees.LastName, Employees.FirstName, COUNT(*) as TotalCount, SUM(julianday(ShippedDate) - julianday(RequiredDate) >= 5) as LateCount FROM ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "*Is there a better approach?*"

[`JOIN`](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/join-operator.html) instead of `UNION` :

```
SELECT
    Employees.EmpID,
    Employees.LastName,
    Employees.FirstName,
    count(*) AS TotalCount,
    sum(
        julianday(Orders.ShippedDate) - julianday(Orders.RequiredDate) >= 5
    )        AS LateCount
FROM
    Employees
JOIN Orders ON Orders.EmpID = Employees.EmpID
GROUP BY
    Employees.EmpID
ORDER BY
    TotalCount DESC,
    LateCount  DESC
```